# Anti Duplicate Form using array if else statement

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, if-statement

I have a code for like RNG rolling table, so that when you input a username it will send the user data and secret hidden number (rng) that generates on page load.

But I have a problem, that the number of RNG sometimes duplicate and time consuming when rolling on seat 30-35.

I tried to solve the problem with if-else statement and an array with array_push function to let the number that already been inputed stored on array, then the if statement to check wheter the number is on array or not, if its stored it must be returned to "reroll" the random number, else then proceed further.

This is my index code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple CRUD by TUTORIALWEB.NET</title>
    <style>
    .kursi{
        width: 70px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: red;
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    }

    .kotakkursi{
        width: 80px;
        height: 60px;
        padding: 10px 2px 10px 2px;
        float: right;
    }

    .kotakkursigenap{
        width: 80px;
        height: 60px;
        padding: 10px 2px 10px 2px;
        float: left;
    }

    .kotakduakursi{
        width: 168px;
        height: 80px;
        padding: 10px 50px 10px 50px;
        float: right;
    }

    .kontbesar{
        width: 840px;
        height: 400px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="kontbesar">
        <?php
        function rng(){
            $x = rand(1,35);
        }

        //iclude file koneksi ke database
        include('koneksi.php');

        //query ke database dg SELECT table siswa diurutkan berdasarkan NIS paling besar
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM siswa ORDER BY siswa_nomer") or die(mysql_error());

        if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0){
            echo '<tr><td colspan="6">Tidak ada data!</td></tr>';
        }

        else{
            $no = 1;
            while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $siswa_nomer = $data['siswa_nomer'];
                if($siswa_nomer < "11"){
                    echo "          
                    <div class='kotakkursi'>
                    <div class='kursi'>"
                    .$data['siswa_nama'].
                    "<br>"
                    .$data['siswa_nomer'].
                    "</div>
                    </div>";
                }
                elseif($siswa_nomer > "10" && $siswa_nomer < "21"){
                    echo "
                    <div class='kotakkursigenap'>
                    <div class='kursi'>"
                    .$data['siswa_nama'].
                    "<br>"
                    .$data['siswa_nomer'].
                    "</div>
                    </div>";
                }

                elseif($siswa_nomer > "20" && $siswa_nomer < "30"){
                    echo "
                    <div class='kotakkursi'>
                    <div class='kursi'>"
                    .$data['siswa_nama'].
                    "<br>"
                    .$data['siswa_nomer'].
                    "</div>
                    </div>";
                }

                elseif($siswa_nomer > "30" ){
                    echo "
                    <div class='kotakkursigenap'>
                    <div class='kursi'>"
                    .$data['siswa_nama'].
                    "<br>"
                    .$data['siswa_nomer'].
                    "</div>
                    </div>";
                }

                }
                $no++;
            }
        ?>

        </div>
        <form action="tambah-proses.php" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="nomer" required value="<?PHP echo $rng; ?>"><br>
                Nama: <input type="text" name="nama" size="30" required>
                <input type="submit" name="tambah" value="Tambah" onclick="rng()">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my file that process the form action (sorry a bit longer because, I dont some stupid manually if-else till 35) :

```
<HTML>
<body onload="gohome()">
<?php
//mulai proses tambah data

//cek dahulu, jika tombol tambah di klik
if(isset($_POST['tambah'])){
    include('koneksi.php');
    $nama   = $_POST['nama'];
    $nomer  = $_POST['nomer'];

    $input = mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());

    $arr = array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    $rng = rand(1, 35);
    function rng(){
    if($nomer != $arr[0] && $arr[0] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[1] && $arr[1] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[2] && $arr[2] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[3] && $arr[3] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[4] && $arr[4] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[5] && $arr[5] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[6] && $arr[6] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[7] && $arr[7] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[8] && $arr[8] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[9] && $arr[9] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[10] && $arr[10] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[11] && $arr[11] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[12] && $arr[12] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[13] && $arr[13] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[14] && $arr[14] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[15] && $arr[15] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[16] && $arr[16] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[17] && $arr[17] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[18] && $arr[18] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[19] && $arr[19] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[20] && $arr[20] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[21] && $arr[21] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[22] && $arr[22] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[23] && $arr[23] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[24] && $arr[24] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[25] && $arr[25] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[26] && $arr[26] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[27] && $arr[27] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[28] && $arr[28] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[29] && $arr[29] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[30] && $arr[30] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[31] && $arr[31] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[32] && $arr[32] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[33] && $arr[33] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################


    elseif($nomer != $arr[34] && $arr[34] = 0){
    if($input){

    $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE nomer='".$nomer."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "roll ulang already exists";
    }

    else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nama', '$nomer')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    }
    }
    }

    else{

    echo 'Gagal menambahkan data! ';    //Pesan jika proses tambah gagal
    echo 'Kembali'; //membuat Link untuk kembali ke halaman tambah

    }
    array_push($arr, $nomer);
    }
    ##########################################################################

    else{
        return 0;
    }
    }
    /*
    else{   //jika tidak terdeteksi tombol tambah di klik

    //redirect atau dikembalikan ke halaman tambah
    echo '<script>window.history.back()</script>';

    }*/

?>
<script>setTimeout(function(){window.location.href='index.php'},2000);</script>
</body>
</HTML>
```

And the SQL if you need it, that store the inputed name and random number :

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.4.5
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Apr 19, 2017 at 08:16 AM
-- Server version: 5.5.16
-- PHP Version: 5.3.8

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `sigizi`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `siswa`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `siswa` (
    `siswa_nama` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `siswa_nomer` int(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`siswa_nomer`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `siswa`
--

-- INSERT INTO `siswa` (`siswa_nama`, `siswa_nis`) VALUES
-- (7, 0, 'Abied Maulana Sofa', 'XII', 'Teknik Komputer dan Jaringan'),
-- (10, 0, 'Hofsatur Rosita', 'XI', 'Akuntansi');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Instead of solving a problem you caused in the first place, why not make sure the secret hidden number (RNG) is always unique? Using numbers 1...35 makes this very difficult. What if there are more than 35 page loads? Is there a special reason to use 1...35? You call them seats? I have really no idea what this code is suppose to do...

Comment: Excuse me, do the unique adds/generate automatically if it detects new form input? or it takes my form that has $_POST['nomer'] (the rng)?

Comment: Normally you would wait until a form is submitted before you assign a unique id.

Comment: How do I assign it then? just create and setting the column, but how do i make it so just an integer consist of number 1-35? Thx

Comment: You would normally use an auto increment column for this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html This way you will be guaranteed that it is a unique value. Please note that the mysql extension is not the best to use, use mysqli or PDO, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php